# php send email: connection timed out

Tags: php

```
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
D8E1D2A5F0      480 Wed Sep 23 14:12:35  administration@rrh.com
(connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[66.102.1.26]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         r.grant.jr.122193@gmail.com

-- 0 Kbytes in 1 Request.
```

PHP:

```
class email{
    function __construct(){

    }
    public function send($to, $from, $subject, $message){
        $header = $this->nl('MIME-Version: 1.0') .
            $this->nl('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8') .
            $this->nl('X-Priority: 1') .
            $this->nl('Importance: High') .
            $this->nl('X-MSMail-Priority: High') . 
            $this->nl('BCC: rick@rrh.com') .
            $this->nl('X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion());
        return mail(
            $to,
            $subject,
            $message,
            $header,
            '-f ' . $from
        );
    }
    private function nl($str){
        return $str . "\r\n";
    }
}

$e = new email();
$e->send('r.grant.jr.122193@gmail.com', 'administration@rrh.com', 'test', 'this is a test');
```

For some reason the email is hanging when sending to gmail but **the blind carbon copy is being sent**!

why is this happening, and how can i fix it?

> Note that administration@rrh.com is not yet setup. Could this be the
>   issue?

Comment: What happens when you set up `administration@rrh.com`?

Comment: Sounds like Google is blocking connections from your server.

Comment: It still hangs but eventually sends (like 2 hours later)

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `rrh.com`, the problem is with sending to `gmail.com`.

Comment: @barmar i think it has to do with my mail daemon

Comment: If it were a problem at your end you would get an error for all destinations, not just gmail.com.

Comment: Well i don't think the problem is with google, google is never the problem

Comment: Hi Wooper C. I ran your script (with different emails) and it worked. I can also telnet to port 25 on 66.102.1.26. Are you able to telnet to 66.102.1.26, port 25 from the sending server and see if you get a connection or timeout?